# Rails migrate add column and populate with data from another column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

If I change my mind about how I store Model data, how might I add new columns and migrate existing data over?

For example, would the following be appropriate:

```
class AddPropertyAAndPropertyBToOwner < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :owners, :property_a, :string
    add_column :owners, :property_b, :string

    # Now I need to migrate the existing 40 records
    # populating the new columns from an existing one
    # Owner.all.each do |o|
    #   original = o.original_property
    #   o.property_a = original.match(/foo/).captures.first
    #   o.proptery_b = original.match(/bar/).captures.first
    #   o.save
    # end
  end
end
```

Comment: it might be useful (or necessary) to split this into `up` and `down` methods

Comment: I see. And in the down methods just dump whatever is in `property_a` & `property_b`?

Comment: Well `down` should simply remove those columns, effectively undoing the `up` method creating and filling them. Keeping the values somewhere is another story. It's just a suggestion since the change method just sort of handles the undoing automatically and I don't know what it would do with the inserts. It might simply fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but you should do [Owner.reset_column_information](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/reset_column_information/class) first

I mean before updating the data.

Comment: Ok excellent. Thanks for the docs link - I'm actually finding it quite hard finding information about available methods!

Comment: No problem.  APIdock is great

Comment: @gotva I will - just need to try it in my dev environment :)